# Node Zlib creating invalid .gz files when streaming

Tags: node.js, stream, zlib

I am trying to create a .gz file by streaming strings (JSONs separated by newlines) to it gradually.

Using Node 0.11 and 0.12 (both with same reasult, .gz  file won't open).

I reduced the code to this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var output = fs.createWriteStream('test.gz');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var compress = zlib.createGzip();
var myStream = compress.pipe(output);

myStream.write('Hello, World!');
myStream.end();
```

The file is created, but I cannot open it. What  am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tried your example, test.gz is created, but is not compressed. I suggest you start by looking into this example [https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_zlib_gzip], which takes an input file, compresses it and than creates another compressed file.

Comment: Right on! I noticed also that the stream is passed uncompressed forward. For some reason, adding a read stream in-front is solving it. But I do not want to go that route, there seems to be an issue here.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, so here's the fix:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var output = fs.createWriteStream('test.gz');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var compress = zlib.createGzip();
/* The following line will pipe everything written into compress to the file stream */
compress.pipe(output);
/* Since we're piped through the file stream, the following line will do: 
   'Hello World!'->gzip compression->file which is the desired effect */
compress.write('Hello, World!');
compress.end();
```

And the explanation:
Piping is used to forward streams from one context to another, each context manipulating the stream according to it's own specification (i.e STDOUT->gzip compression->encryption->file will cause everything printed to STDOUT to pass gzip compression, encryption and eventually write to file).

In your original example, you are writing to the *end* of the pipe, this means writing to the file with no manipulations and hence you got the plain ASCII you asked to write. The confusion here is about what myStream is. You assumed it is the entire chain (gzip->file) but in fact, it is just the end (file).

Once a pipe is set to a stream object, all further writes to that stream will pipe through automatically when you write to the original stream.

Some references I found useful:
http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html#what_are_transform_streams_

http://www.sitepoint.com/basics-node-js-streams/

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Comment: Interesting but how do you compress and encrypt a stream? `pg_dump_process.stdout
     .pipe(new str2buf())
     .pipe(cipher)          // Encrypt the data
     .pipe(stream_to_s3(bucket, database.folder, s3)) // Stream the data to S3`? I don't know where to put the gzip object :)